# How to install Pillow on Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

As the title suggested I have trouble installing Pillow on Python 3.5.2. I believe I already have pip and easyinstall preinstalled. I have viewed some tutorials and attempted to type '>$pip install Pillow' into the IDLE shell but it came back with a syntax error. I am new to programming and have no prior IT exprience so please be specific and put it in simple terms. My OS is Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the the output of `pip` , the error message?

Comment: 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' with the '$' highlighted

Comment: Idle is just to enter Python code, you have to open a Windows' command window and from its prompt give the command `pip install pillow` — Of course the executable file for `pip` must be in your path.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo pip3 install Pillow` - unix-style

`pip install Pillow` - windows

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html

Comment: @DaveOink , please add your operation system

Comment: Find directory, where python3 is installed (usually it is C:

Comment: C:\Python35). Go to 'Scripts' (where pip.exe is). Press shift and click right mouse button, then choose new command window or something like that. And there (in cmd) type 'pip.exe install Pillow'

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow==5.0.0
```

This will saves you

Answer (score 1):

Installing stuff on ms-windows is such a can of worms that it is probably easiest to use a specialized Python distribution for ms-windows, like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Enghought](https://www.enthought.com/). These come with a lot of packages pre-installed, and have their own package managers to make adding more stuff easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip install Pillow. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try typing `pip` in the command line maybe you didn't install pip properly
if you didn't then go to [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to install pip

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question directly. Please edit your answer providing more details regarding resolving the problem in this thread. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer